# Showing that a function is primitively recursive

Tags: recursion, computability

> Let $ f \colon \mathbb{N}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{N} $ be a primitively recursive function, and let $ g \colon \mathbb{N}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{N} $ be defined as:
> $$ g(x,y)=\min \{f(0,y), f(1,y),...,f(x,y)\}, x,y \in \mathbb{N}.$$
> Prove that $g$ is primitevely recursive.

My idea was to write the function $g$ in the bracket form of cases, where the cases would represent predicates. The problem is that then the predicates would not be mutually exclusive ( there could be $f(i,y)=f(j,y) , i \neq j $)

Comment: $\min (n,m)$ is primitive recursive: do you know its def ?

Comment: $\min(x_1, \ldots, x_n , x_{n+1}) = \min(\min(x_1, \ldots, x_n), x_{n+1})$

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA The definition of $g$ applies min with a variable number $x+1$ of arguments.

Answer (score 2):

$g(0,y)=f(0,y)$ and $g(x+1,y)=\min(g(x,y),f(x+1,y))$.